# Upload backup files on Azure file storage from Ubuntu server

Tags: azure, backup, file-storage

I need to upload my backup files from my Ubuntu server to Azure file storage, unable to upload it. Please share any idea or suggestions for the same.

Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: Azure file storage? do you mean Azure file share service?

Comment: Please tell us what have you tried so far and what is the issue you're running into.

Comment: I don't  know exactly what is best to store backup .tar file on azure storage. my requirement is to upload my gitlab backup files on azure storage. but where to store is still unclear. you should suggest me which is useful for me.

Comment: @HeenaPatel If you just want to store the backup files, we can use Azure blobs, if you want to store and share them, we can use azure file share, more information i have post in my answer, please check it.

Answer (score 1):

You just want to store the your gitlab backup files? or want store and share them?

If you just want to store them, I think we can create Azure storage blobs to store backup files. In Linux we can **install** Azure [CLI 1.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cli-install-nodejs) or Azure [CLI 2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli) to **upload** files to Azure blobs.
More information about how to use [CLI 1.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-azure-cli-nodejs) or [CLI 2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-azure-cli) to upload files to Azure, please refer to the link.

If you want to store and share the backup files, I think we can use Azure file share storage. Azure files share service same as SMB 3.0, so you can **mount** the Azure file share to your Ubuntu, in this way, you can upload the backup files to it. Then you can mount Azure file share service to others to share the backup files.

More information about Azure file share service, please refer to the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-how-to-use-files-linux).

Comment: Please let me know if you would like further assistance.

Comment: Thank you so much Sir, but now we are going to upload our gitlab backup on AWS S3.

Comment: Just wanted to add that the CLI is the best way to achieve this. Do you use your Ubuntu server within Azure environment or you have it on-prem?

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought of implementing some agent tool to backup the data from Ubuntu to Azure Cloud storage? I think it can be a way out. Have a look at Cloudberry. It may help you. I see no other way to help which does not take so much time and effort.

Answer (score 0):

Azure File Storage on-premises access from across all regions for Linux distribution - Ubuntu 17.04 is now supported right out of the box and no extra setup is needed.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-file-storage-on-premises-access-for-ubuntu/